# File pathway field cannot be filled with Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, input, autocomplete, selenium-chromedriver

I tried to add a path to file that needs to be uploaded with Selenium (Chromedriver) and failed. My doubt is if it is possible with tag autocomplete="off".
Input:

```
<input id="loadFileControl-1287-inputEl" type="text" role="textbox" size="1" name="" readonly="readonly" class="x-form-field x-form-required-field x-form-text x-form-invalid-field x-form-focus x-field-form-focus x-field-default-form-focus" autocomplete="off" data-errorqtip="<ul class=&quot;x-list-plain&quot;><li>This field is required</li></ul>" style="width: 100%;">
```

My attempt in Selenium:

```
input_field = driver.find_element("xpath", "//input[@class='x-form-field x-form-required-field x-form-text x-form-invalid-field x-form-focus x-field-form-focus x-field-default-form-focus']")
input_field.send_keys('file_name.xml')
```

`input_field.click()` works so I assume I point the element correctly.
Thank you.

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: There is no error. Nothing changes after sending keys. Sorry, I made a mistake, the autocomplete is on 'off'.

Comment: maybe just use ID `loadFileControl-1287-inputEl` locator and not a mile long class locator.

Comment: I tried that too but unfortunately result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

The field youre trying to input into is read only. You can click on it but like the attribute says, you cant edit it.

`<input id="loadFileControl-1287-inputEl" type="text" role="textbox" size="1" name="" readonly="readonly" class="x-form-field x-form-required-field x-form-text x-form-invalid-field x-form-focus x-field-form-focus x-field-default-form-focus" autocomplete="off" data-errorqtip="<ul class=&quot;x-list-plain&quot;><li>This field is required</li></ul>" style="width: 100%;">`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I understand there is no way I can indicate the file location with Selenium? Click on the finding button opens File Explorer.

Comment: youre describing an entirely different problem now. No you cant edit a readonly field (you could fiddle with javascript but i cant recommend it in this situation. If you want to upload a file with file explorer you can look into `pyautogui`